# add style to excel file

Tags: typescript, sheetjs

I'm reading an Excel file, and then exporting it, but the file doesn't have any style, although I'm reading a designed file.

Here is my code sample:

```
oReq.onload = function (e) {
      var arraybuffer = oReq.response;
      /* convert data to binary string */
      var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
      var arr = new Array();
      for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i)
        arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      var bstr = arr.join("");

      /* Call XLSX */
      var workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
        type: "binary",
        cellStyles: true,
        cellFormula :true
      });
      /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];

      /* Get worksheet */
      var worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

      for (let row = 8, row2 = 9, i = 0; i < self.teachersList.length - 1; row = row + 2, row2 = row2 + 2, i++) {

        var t = "B" + row;
        var flag = true;

        XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(
          worksheet,
          [
            {
              B: self.teachersList[i].id1,
              C: self.teachersList[i].name,
             ....
            }
          ],
          { skipHeader: true, origin: t }
        );

      XLSX.writeFile(workbook, "sheetjs.xlsx", { cellStyles: true });

    };

    oReq.send();
```

I tried to use `xlsx-style`, but it didn't work. Is there any way to read the Excel file including his style? I turned `cellstyle` to true but it looks that it doesn't matter.

Comment: What package are you using to read the Excel file? It sounds like the issue is there, rather than with Angular or Typescript

Comment: are you using SheetJS js-xlsx?

Comment: SheetJS js-xlsx community version provided at https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx does not support features like styling. There exists a pro version (https://sheetjs.com/pro) that offers such support.

Comment: I'm using  import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

Comment: please, help, I'm spending hours looking for an answer, I must style my excel document, do there is any way?